# If $|z + \mathrm i| = |z|$ and $\arg\frac{z + \mathrm i}{z} = \frac{\pi}{4}$, then find $z$

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

When I solved the question, I got $\mathrm i = 0$, which is not possible. I there a way I am missing here. I solved it by taking tan inverse.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to **show what you've already tried**, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Please show your work. We can then point out the mistake in your argument.

Comment: I quote the comment above. BTW, here is a little hint, you should find two points on the complex plane at the end.

Comment: Did you try to solve by drawing on the complex plane? It can be easier.

Comment: Set $Z:=\frac{z+i}{z}$, you know that the modulus of $Z$ is $1$ and its argument is $\pi/4$. Conclusion Z= ? Knowing Z, it is easy to retrieve $z$...

Comment: @Marco I don't see why there should be 2 solutions (see my comment above).

Comment: My bad, I wrote it wrongly. $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+0.5-\frac{i}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|z+i|=|z|\implies z=x-\frac{1}{2}i$
So, $arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z}\right)=\pi/4$
$\implies arg(x+\frac{1}{2}i)-arg(x-\frac{1}{2}i)=\pi/4$
$\implies tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2x})-tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{-2x})=\pi/4$
$\implies 2tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2x})-\pi=\pi/4$
$\implies tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2x})=5\pi/8$
$\implies \frac{1}{2x}=tan(5\pi/8)=\sqrt{\frac{1-cos 5\pi/4}{1+cos 5\pi/4}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 2+1}{\sqrt 2-1}}$
$\implies x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt 2+1}}$
Thus, the required set is $\{x+iy\in\mathbb C:x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt 2+1}}\}$

Comment: Did you missed $y=-\frac{1}{2}$ in the answer?

Comment: No, he took it up..

Comment: The final answer looks like a whole line of solution.

Comment: I think $2\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2x})=\frac{\pi}{4}$, thus $x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

Method 2: You can use a geometry approach, then use trigonometry to find the answer.

Consider OAB in complex plane. A = z. B = z+i.

$|z|=|z+i|$ means OA=OB

$arg\frac{z+i}{z}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ means $\angle AOB = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\angle AOB$ is in anti-clockwise direction.

Then you need A in 4th quadrant and B in 1st quadrant.

Since AB $\perp$ x-axis. Let AB meet x-axis at point P. We have AP=PB=$\frac{1}{2}$.
and $\angle AOP = \angle BOP = \frac{\pi}{8}$. (Skipped some geometry argument)

Then $OP=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\tan\frac{\pi}{8}}=\frac{1}{2\tan\frac{\pi}{8}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}\approx1.207$

Then $z= OP-APi=\frac{1}{2\tan\frac{\pi}{8}}- \frac{1}{2} i$

Answer (score 0):

$|z+i|=|z|$ represents perpendicular bisector of the segment between $z=-i$ and $z=0$, hence $z=-i/2 \implies y=-1/2$, let $z=x-i/2$, then
$$W=\frac{z+i}{z}=\frac{x+i/2}{x-i/2}=\frac{(x+i/2)^2}{x^2+1/4}=\frac{x^2-1/4+ix}{x^2+1/4}$$
Next, $Arg[W]=\pi/4$  implies that $x^2>1/4$ and $x>0,$ $$\frac{x}{x^2-1/4}= \tan \pi/4 \implies x^2-x-1/4=0, x=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}$$
So all required sollutions are $$z=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

> Recall: if $s$ satisfies $|s|=r$ and $\arg(s)=\theta$ then $s=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta$

> Put $s=\dfrac{z+i}z$ then $|s|=1$ and $\arg(s)=\dfrac\pi4$ i.e $s=\mathrm e^{i\pi/4}=\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$

> The question is now equivalent to solve for $z$ the equation $\dfrac {z+i}z=s$ where $s=
> \dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$